# ObjectMapper Deserializated Especific Third Party Field

Tags: java, spring

I have a Software that's call to a Google API, i can't use Google Libraries for call, but yes for model. So i'm calling to Google API across RestTemplate. The problem come when RestTemplate try deserializate using ObjectMapper a DateTime Object of Google.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.google.api.client.util.DateTime field com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Events.updated to java.lang.String
```

So, i need modify ObjectMapper try it to decode a DateTime class, the objectMapper calls a interface that give me the oportunity to deserializated manually.

I try with Modules and Deserializators, but they only when you put it on top class or put a annotation on variable, but my class is of third party so i can't modify.

Also i try with mixin but they must put al variables and this cost a lot of time, because Google class have a lot of fields, and break the injection of dependencies.

Comment: what is the format of the date you get from google?

Comment: 2002-10-02T10:00:00-05:00 (RFC3339 date/times)